# Create EC2 Userdata for AWS EC2 using Powershell with Terraform challenge

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, terraform

Honestly I have spent an absolute eternity trying to install the SSM Agent and get it to work on a Windows EC2 (base AMI) launched via Terraform.  All I need it to do is launch a EC2 instance (Windows) with the SSM agent installed ( I believe this comes by default, but unless I'm hallucinating on magic mushrooms I just cannot connect to it when it's provisioned in the console - says error SSM agent not installed) - It has ADMIN privileges also and has instance profile with the god mode.  I also need the TF Userdata to **create a folder on boot** and it's totally not happening.  Any ideas?  Thanks.   Here's the powershell userdata. (p.s) - instance launches ok, it's just not accepting userdata on launch.

```
            <powershell>
            Invoke-WebRequest `
                https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/windows_amd64/AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe 
                -OutFile $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\SSMAgent_latest.exe

            Start-Process `
                -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\SSMAgent_latest.exe `
                -ArgumentList "/S"

            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Cats
            <powershell>
```

Comment: The instance role used, it does not work only for windows ec2? If you apply the same role for linux instance, ssm works?

Comment: I have not tried Linux.  BUT, i'm pretty sure it would work as there's 1000000000000000000 articles online explaining how to achieve this.  BUT, for Windows with EC2 userdata and Powershell comands it's few and far between.  Any ideas?

Comment: If my file name for the Powershell userdata is ended with a .txt what do i need to enter in main.tf to reference it?  would it be ```user_data  = "${local_file.user_data.txt.content}"

Comment: So you are using custom vpc? Is the intance launched in public subnet or private with nat gateway?

Comment: Yeah all in a public subnet

Comment: Windows2016 and Windows2019 official AMIs do come with the SSM agent pre-installed. If the userdata is "not working", then try verifying the userdata is loaded from the console, and then debug the PS script itself.

Comment: this is fixed. The solution was that in fact the instance when spinning up with Terraform DIDN'T have the line "associate_public_ip_address = true" - ...... How do you get it to run without this being assigned?  Nothing should be public especially compute.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you get it to run without this being assigned? Nothing should be public especially compute.

Since the primary issue has been solved (see comments) I can comment on the above question.

By definition if an instance is in public subnet, it will be publicly available with the public IP assigned. To ensure that your instances are **private** but can still connect internet, three things are required:

- a **private subnet** without a route to internet gateway,
- [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in a public subnet
- **route table** of the private subnet must be configured to route internet traffic to the NAT gateway.

With this setup, launching an instance in the private subnet ensures that it will be able to access internet (e.g. to download software or updates), but it will bo **non-accessible** from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the following

- IAM role created
- Instance role with appropriate policies attached
- ec2 instance in the correct subnet with internet access